# Zooming multiple UIImageView contents in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I got some problem when i'm zooming, when i zoom the next UIImageView goes above the UIImageView i m zooming in.

I load my UIImageView in a subclass of a UIScrollView that i call in controller. The load function and Scroll function work perfectly.

**The first problem** is that when I zoom in the next UIImageView goes above the one that i m zooming in.

So i tried to put every UIImageView in a UIView that i put into the ScrollView but it does the same things...

**The 2nd problem** that I have is that when i zoom in, my scroll doesn't work anymore.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scroll.pagingEnabled=YES;

    NSInteger numberOfViews = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
        image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]]];

        image.frame=CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

      [scroll addSubview:image];
   }

   scroll.maximumZoomScale=6.0;
   scroll.minimumZoomScale=0.5;
   scroll.delegate=self;
   scroll.clipsToBounds=YES;


   scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);

   [self.view addSubview:scroll];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return image;
}
```

**I know that there are questions similar to this** but nothing helps my cause.Any suggested changes in my code to make it correct is more than appreciated.

Comment: check out zooming and paging here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Comment: @NeverHopeless I already did thanks for your google search.I am not using Paging,I am using a single UIImageView

Comment: Is not using paging then why this `scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;` ? Also, how do you zoom when you have min/max zoom scales equal to 1.0 ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless. Sorry i meant to say page control. zoom scale values i was testing with different values. I edited the code.

Comment: @NeverHopeless do you know the answer ??

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the problem and the controls hierarchy ?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView : (UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
     return _image3;
     _image3.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     _image3.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
}


-(void)  tapfucntion : (UIGestureRecognizer *)  guesture
{ 
    if  (self.scroll.zoomScale >_ scroll.minimumZoomScale )
        [self.scroll setZoomScale:_scroll.minimumZoomScale animated:YES];
    else
        [self.scroll setZoomScale:2.0 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: what is image3??.please do use words also to explain what is happening in your answer code

Comment: for zooming u just use guesture recogniser... and for zooming in scrollview u just make that user interaction enabled... and that function is for tap guesture ... means when u double tap the image it will zoom ... write that function in ur code it works

Comment: its below add that in view did load

Comment: Are you new to objective c.I don't have enough reputation or else i would have voted ur answer down for useless and wrong answers.See the code it tells how image is taken from my bundle.

Answer (score 0):

in ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   _tap = [ [ UITapGestureRecognizer  alloc ]  initWithTarget : self action :  @selector( tapfucntion: ) ] ;

   _tap.numberOfTapsRequired=2;

   [self.scroll addGestureRecognizer: _tap];
}
```

Comment: Things can be done without tapping too i am k with pinch itself. Irrelavent answers

Comment: in viewForZoomingInScrollView

Comment: Did i say my image is not zooming.My question is that it is not zooming properly;which means user interaction is already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `CollectionView` to overcome that problem. Using Storyboard to create easily.

1. Create `collectionview` with `customCell` inside a cell add scrollview and imageview.
2. Set `ScrollViewDelegate` to `CollectionViewCell`.
3. Add this delegate method in `collectionviewCellClass`.

   `- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
           return [scrollView viewWithTag:imageView];
       }`